# Extraction an array from JSON string in spark

Tags: json, apache-spark, lift

I am receiving a JSON String on kafka topic of form

```
{"user_id":"4BtIrO4vgJUZG3wUxDjihnKbYvw2","travel_mode":"plane","travel_with":["family","couple"],"travel_preferences":"national"}
```

Now I am using this JSON String in spark and extracting it by

```
var jValue: JValue=net.liftweb.json.JsonParser.parse(st)
val mailServer = jValue.extract[Reg]
```

by this I am able to extract all the other things except `travel_with` which is an array. So please tell me how to extract that array.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

write a case class Reg of the form 
case class Reg(user_id: String, travel_mode: String, travel_with: List[String],travel_preferences: String)
and then you will get travel_with of the form List[ a, b]